# I don't have an undock button on the start bar after I dock my laptop?

Tags: windows-7, docking-station

Dell E6510, i7, windows 7 32bit: fresh install, previously running XP sp3.

I thought the issue had to do with the XP install, but I still have the same problem.  After I dock my laptop, my only option is to just "rip it off" the dock using the "eject" button which does nothing but physically detach the connectors.  Its really frustrating more than anything.

really hard to google this also, since dock/button/undock are used in so many different contexts.

Comment: go to google and type in: undock option dell e6510  "The replicator is "Hot Swappable" so you will not see an "Undock" command. You just undock it. My E6510 docks and undocks fine now."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the Win7 way.  No need to Tell the OS you are going to undock.  It detects it after the fact and reconfigures as needed.

Comment: These models don't have the undock option in xp either, assuming they are similar to the e6500's. The dock doesn't use a separate hardware profile, so you have to use the dell app if you want settings to change upon 'undocking'.

Comment: Not so lucky here. I have the Dell E6510 and PR0X2 dock and when I undock, the screen does not come on on the laptop. I have to hard-power it down and then restart the laptop after undocking.  Or shutdown before undocking (which defeats the purpose).